# Do intents no longer work for posting images on Facebook?

Tags: java, android, facebook, android-intent, sdk

I created an app some time back, using intents. Now it is not working. I learned somewhere that text and image posting through intents are not allowed. I just want to confirm this is the case.

If this is true, then is the only method to post via the Facebook SDK or are there any other simple ways to do it?

Comment: You have to use facebook sdk https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is utilize the facebook graph api to do HTTP requests on behalf of the user to the facebook server using the access token.

In order to get the access token you need to implement the facebook login, you need to be familiar with oauth and oauth2 protocols for doing this.
Once you have the access token you can post the image to the facebook account at the `/me/photos`endpoint. 
Store you image in a Bitmap. And use the following code.

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(
        "https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos?access_token="
                + AccessTokens.fbaccesstoken);
MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(
        HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bos);
byte[] data = bos.toByteArray();
entity.addPart("source", new ByteArrayBody(data, "myImage.jpg"));
entity.addPart("message", new StringBody(caption.getText()
        .toString()));
httpPost.setEntity(entity);
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost,localContext);
```

The facebook sdk is built on top of this API, the sdk considerably reduces the complexity in using these features for us developers.

P.S: Facebook has a review for any apps trying to implement oauth login. More info at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review